# DataGridView not updating through Event

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have an EventHandler DonorUpdatedHandler() in a c# WinForm that updates a datagridview through a method RefreshGridData() in which I assign the datasource again. The RefreshGridData() is called when event fired but the grid never updates. BTW, RefreshGridData() works fine from a Form.Activated event handler. Can you suggest why?

```
        private void gridDonors_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            var sendergrid = (DataGridView)sender;

            if(sendergrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn && e.RowIndex >=0)
            {
                int id = (int) sendergrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["id"].Value;
                frmAddDonor frmDonor = new frmAddDonor();
                frmDonor.editMode = true;
                frmDonor.DonorUpdated += new System.EventHandler(this.DonorUpdatedHandler);
                frmDonor.Show();
                frmDonor.LoadRecordById(id);
            }
        }

        private void RefreshGridData()
        {
            BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
            BindingList<Donor> list = new BindingList<Donor>(donorModel.all());
            source.DataSource = list;
            gridDonors.DataSource = source;
        }

        private void DonorUpdatedHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RefreshGridData();    
        }
```

Comment: Please do not link your code, but add the relevant parts of it to the question. See [mcve]. Please also refer to [ask].

Comment: Have you tried calling "ResetBindings" manually?   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.resetbindings(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The grid refreshes fine if RefreshGridData() is called from a Form.Activated event.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the problem. Nothing wrong in the code. It was the issue of synchronization of writes and reads with the Jet OLE DB Provider. I was writing and reading through different OleDbConnections. I have used a Singleton and that apparently solved the problem. Thanks.

Details:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/200300/how-to-synchronize-writes-and-reads-with-the-jet-ole-db-provider-and-a